# Retrieving all records based on a specific month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

my dates in my table are strings in the format:

```
"10/12/2009"
```

Now how would one get all the records from a month, lets say June (number "6" being provided)?

Comment: Really, the best solution is to change the column to store a proper MySQL datetime instead of this format.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: That said, `MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(yourdate, '%M/%d/%Y')) = 6`

Comment: So.. "SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5,2011','%m,%Y'); FROM $table LIMIT 30;"? As I said I want all months not just a specific day!

Comment: How would one write this as a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you can use the `STR_TO_DATE` and `MONTH` functions to 1) convert the string representation into a DATE, and 2) extract the month component from the date:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(t.dateasstringcol,'%M/%d/%Y')) = 6
```

(This is assuming here that by '10/12/2009', you are specifying Oct 12, and not Dec 10. You'd need to adjust the format string if that's not the case.)

Alternatively, if month is indeed the leading part of the date, you could do a simple string comparison, if the month is the leading component:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.dateasstringcol LIKE '6/%' 
    OR t.dateasstringcol LIKE '06/%'
```

(You could eliminate one of those predicates, if you have an exact format specified for the striing value representing the date: either if month is always stored as two digits -OR- the month is never stored with a leading zero.)

If you are passing in an argument for the month, e.g. '6', then you could construct your statement something like this:

```
 WHERE t.dateasstringcol LIKE '6' + '/%'
```

If month is the second component of the date, then you could use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.dateasstringcol LIKE '%/' + '6' + '/%' 
    OR t.dateasstringcol LIKE '%/' + '06' + /%'
```

**NOTE:**

All of the previous example queries will return rows for June of any year (2009, 2010, 2011)

You can extend those examples, and do something similar with the year, using the YEAR function in place of the MONTH function, or for string comparison

```
    AND t.dateasstringcol LIKE '%/%/2011'
```

Normally, we'd extract rows for a particular month for a particular year, using a date range, for example:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(t.dateasstring,'%M/%d/%Y')) >= '2011-06-01'
   AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(t.dateasstring,'%M/%d/%Y')) <  '2011-07-01'
```

Of course, when the date value is stored as a `DATE` datatype rather than as a VARCHAR, this means we don't need the STR_TO_DATE and MONTH functions, we can specify a comparison to the native DATE column.  This approach allows us to make use of an index on the date column, which can improve query performance on large tables.

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.realdatecol >= '2011-06-01'
   AND t.realdatecol <  '2011-07-01'
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the best answer! this is what I waslooking for: $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d/%m/%Y')) = $month";

Answer (score 3):

Check the MySQL function [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

You should not store dates as string, however. Use the type DATE.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that dates should not be stored in this format.

Comment: I agree that they shouldn't not my database though :(

Answer (score 0):

The STR_TO_DATE function is your friend here:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('10/12/2009','%M/%d/%Y') >= '2012-06-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

[MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) should help here if we want current month or particular month data. e.g:

```
$month = date('m'); OR particular month.
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(str_to_date("10/12/2009",'%e/%m/%Y')) = $month;
```